# c14n with Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to make an xml in canonical form on android?

The canonicalizers from some apache projects don't work as they depend on some javax.xml.* packages which aren't available on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution: The Canonizer used in the XOM Project (http://www.xom.nu/) runs on android.